# Either way vs both ways

Tags: phrase-choice

In this context,

A says, Let's do it in this way.

B says, Let's do it in that way.

And then they ask me my opinion. I don't have a strong opinion on it. Then what should I say?

1. I'm okay with both ways.
2. I'm okay with either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second is clearer; method A or method B (but not both together) can be used and I will be content. The first *might* be taken as agreeing to the two methods being used together. If it is clearly impossible to use them together the meanings would be the same.

There are sentences where it does matter. If I had said "I'm OK if you use both ways" I would be approving the combination, not the separate methods.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's much clear for me now.